# Java project: number of students that passed or fail?? Logical error

Tags: java

So this code asks to input either a 1 for a pass or a 2 for a fail for ten students and it shows an error if the user inputs an invalid number. The logical error in this is for example all 10 students pass,the output is supposed to be "passed: 10 Failed:0".However, if I enter an error just once by mistake the error message will appear but the output will be"passed:9 failed:0 " even thought all 10 students passed.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class pass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int passes = 0;
        int failures = 0;
        int result;

        for (int studentCounter = 1; studentCounter <= 10; studentCounter++) {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter (1=pass, 2= fail)");
            result = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (result == 1) {
                passes = passes + 1;
            } else if (result == 2) {
                failures = failures + 1;
            } else if ((result != 1) && (result != 2)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error input 1 or 2");

            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Passed:" + passes + "Failed:" + failures);
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be increasing the `studentCounter` when there was an error. The easiest way to achieve that would be to do `studentCounter--` after the error dialog.

Comment: so error should be out of the loop?

Comment: First of all, you should use the Oracle Java Code Conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/codeconvtoc-136057.html...
failures ++; passes++;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is executed exactly 10 times. But if an error occurs, your code neither increases `passes` nor `failures`, and therefore `passes` + `failures` always is the amount of inputs without failures and always <= 10.

If you want to have exactly 10 results you have to make sure that there are exactly 10 correct inputs.
You can achieve this by increasing a results counter on correct inputs until it reaches 10:

```
int studentCounter = 0;
while(studentCounter < 10 ){
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter (1=pass, 2= fail)");
    result = Integer.parseInt(input);
    if(result==1){
            passes++;
            studentCounter++;
    }else if(result==2){
            failures++;
            studentCounter++;
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error input 1 or 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, should be correct with initial value 0. Did you check for `while(studentCounter <= 10 )` in your implementation (mind the `=`)?

Comment: I didn't use the equal sign and i initialized to zero not one my mistake

Answer (score 2):

It is right, as 9 have passed and 0 have failed. The error does not count in none of the groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code like below to remove your logical error:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class pass{
public static void main(String [] args){
int passes=0;
int failures=0;
int result;


for(int studentCounter = 1; studentCounter<=10;){
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter (1=pass, 2= fail)");
    result = Integer.parseInt(input);
    if(result==1){
            passes = passes + 1;
            studentCounter++
    }else if(result==2){
            failures = failures +1;
            studentCounter++
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error input 1 or 2");

    }
}
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Passed:"+passes+"Failed:"+failures);
            System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your if else logic:
Your `For` loop increments the integer in the condition `else if((result!=1)&&(result!=2))` which means that for example, if you make 10 times a input other than 1 or 2, you'll get a result like 0 passes and 0 failed... but your loop is over....

I suggest you additionally to use the [Oracle Java Code Conventions](http://oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/codeconvtoc-136057.html)... failures ++; passes++;

Answer (score 1):

You can have try with below code. Decrements student counter on invalid input.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class pass{
    public static void main(String [] args){
int passes=0;
int failures=0;
int result;

for(int studentCounter = 1; studentCounter<=10; studentCounter++){
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter (1=pass, 2= fail)");
    result = Integer.parseInt(input);
    if(result==1){
            passes++;
    }else if(result==2){
            failures++;
    } else if((result!=1)&&(result!=2)) {
        studentCounter--;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error input 1 or 2");

    }
}

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Passed:"+passes+" Failed:"+failures);
            System.exit(0);
}
}
```